# Unknown option "-text" (tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to display text from a database on the screen once a button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

vfr_import = PhotoImage(file="Images/vfr.png")
r_vfr = vfr_import.subsample(3, 3)

class Airfields(Button):
  def __init__(self, master, image, command, location):
    Button.__init__(self, master, image=image, command=command)
    self.style = {"bg":"#7D7D7D","bd":0,"highlightbackground":"#7D7D7D","highlightthickness":0}
    self.place(x=location[0], y=location[1])
    self.config(self.style)

class TextBox(Text):
  def __init__(self, master, text, location):
    Text.__init__(self, master, text=text)
    self.style = {"bg":"Black","font":"(Arial, 12)"}
    self.place(x=location[0], y=loaction[1])
    self.config(self.style)

def display_info(location):
  name = TextBox(root, str(c.execute("""SELECT Name FROM Airfields WHERE ICAO = (?)""", (location,))), [500,300])

Andrewsfield = Airfields(root, r_vfr, display_info('EGSL'), [255, 375])
```

However I get the error `TclError: unknown option "-text"`

Comment: Instead of `Text.__init__(self, master, text=text)`, use `Text.__init__(self, master)` and `self.insert("end", text)`. That is only if you want a `Text` widget instead of a `Label`

Comment: When I try running the updated code, I get the error: "TextBox object has no attribute 'insert'" ?

Comment: `Button`, `Text`, `loaction`, `root`, `r_vfr` are all undefined ?  presumably some come from `import tkinter` ?  users need a min reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes Button and Text are from tkinter, root is the parent (root=Tk()), r_vfr is an image import. Location is used to place the images.
I'll add the rest of the needed code to the original post

Comment: The error is saying exactly what is wrong: the `Text` widget doesn't support a `text` option.

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Oakley said, the `Text` widget doesn't use a `-text` parameter to insert text. The `Text` widget has a method called `insert`, which takes an index for the first parameter and chars in the second. Tags and additional characters can follow.

> ```
> def insert(self, index, chars, *args):
>     Insert CHARS before the characters at INDEX. An additional
>     tag can be given in ARGS. Additional CHARS and tags can follow in ARGS.
> ```

So your code would look like this: (I've formatted it to PEP8 style guidelines)

BTW your code indent should be four spaces, not two.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")

vfr_import = PhotoImage(file="Images/vfr.png")
r_vfr = vfr_import.subsample(3, 3)


class Airfields(Button):
  def __init__(self, master, image, command, location):
    Button.__init__(self, master, image=image, command=command)
    self.style = {"bg": "#7D7D7D", "bd": 0,
                  "highlightbackground": "#7D7D7D", "highlightthickness": 0}
    self.place(x=location[0], y=location[1])
    self.config(self.style)


class TextBox(Text):
  def __init__(self, master, text, location):
    Text.__init__(self, master)
    self.insert(0, text)
    self.style = {"bg": "Black", "font": "(Arial, 12)"}
    self.place(x=location[0], y=loaction[1])
    self.config(self.style)


def display_info(location):
  name = TextBox(root, str(c.execute(
      """SELECT Name FROM Airfields WHERE ICAO = (?)""", (location,))), [500, 300])


Andrewsfield = Airfields(root, r_vfr, display_info('EGSL'), [255, 375])
```